# VBA: Sub to Write to a Log File

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of macros defined in my workbook, and I'd like to offer the user the option to log events related to those macros in a log file.

I initiate the log by creating the following in ThisWorkbook:

```
Public writeLog as Boolean
Public logWrite as Object
Public log as Object
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    Dim prompt as Integer
    prompt = MsgBox("Would you like to log events for this session?", vbYesNo, "Log Events?")
    If prompt Then
        writeLog = True
        Set logWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set log = logWrite.CreateTextFile("C:/TEST.txt", False)
    Else
        writeLog = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I then created a procedure that I can use to write an argument to this object, which I've stored in its own module:

```
Public Sub PrintLog(obj as Object, argument as String)
    If writeLog = True Then
        obj.WriteLine argument
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why: even if I don't include `obj` as an argument to the function (since `log` and `logWrite` were created as global variables), I'm not able to `Call WriteLog("String here.")` or `Call WriteLog(log, "String here.")` without an error (`Compile Error: Argument Not Optional.`)

Is it possible to get such a `Sub()` to work, so that I can call it from anywhere in the workbook (after a button is pressed in a userform, for example) without having to define a new `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in every module?

Comment: You can write the routine to initiate the log in the same module as the `WriteLog` Sub. Then just call it in the `Worksheet_Open` event

Comment: Should I initiate the connection (`Set logWrite`, `Set log`) in the procedure every time, in that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you can solve your problem by making some minor changes to your code. I tried the following setup:

logger module:

```
Option Explicit

Private log As Object

Public Sub initLog()

    Dim prompt As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim fso As Object

    prompt = MsgBox("Would you like to log events for this session?", vbYesNo, "Log Events?")

    If prompt = vbYes Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set log = fso.CreateTextFile("C:/TEST.txt", False)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub PrintLog(argument As String)
    If Not log Is Nothing Then
        log.WriteLine argument
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub yadda()
    'test
    PrintLog "yadda"
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    initLog
End Sub
```

Comment: what about if it already exists?

Answer (score 2):

This is my drop in replacement for Debug.Print(), that logs to the Immediate Window so you can watch your program progress, and to the file "Log.txt" at your Excel Workbook path.

**To install** : Just search and replace "Debug.Print" with "Log", and add the Log() function below.

```
Public Function Log(ByRef a_stringLogThis As String)
    ' prepare date
    l_stringDateTimeNow = Now
    l_stringToday = Format(l_stringDateTimeNow, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")
    ' concatenate date and what the user wants logged
    l_stringLogStatement = l_stringToday & " " & a_stringLogThis
    ' send to TTY
    Debug.Print (l_stringLogStatement)
    ' append (not write) to disk
    Open ThisWorkbook.path & "\Log.txt" For Append As #1
    Print #1, l_stringLogStatement
    Close #1
End Function
```

**OPTIONAL** : And here's a helper LogClear() you COULD call at the beginning of your program, to erase previous logging.

```
Public Function LogClear()
    Debug.Print ("Erasing the previous logs.")
    Open ThisWorkbook.path & "\Log.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, ""
    Close #1
End Function
```

Comment: For me: best thing since sliced bread

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having issues as writeLog already exists as a boolean.  Error should be popping up "Ambiguous name detected"

Try the following,

```
Public bLog as Boolean
Public logWrite as Object
Public log as Object
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    Dim prompt as Integer
    prompt = MsgBox("Would you like to log events for this session?", vbYesNo, "Log Events?")
    If prompt Then
        bLog = True
        Set logWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set log = logWrite.CreateTextFile("C:/TEST.txt", False)
    Else
        bLog = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub WriteLog(Optional obj as Object, Optional argument as String)
    If bLog = True Then
        obj.WriteLine argument
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:  made parameters optional in WriteLog (or PrintLog) for further testing

Comment: I do apologize: that's an oversight on my part when writing the code in SO. The boolean and the function are named differently in my code, like in yours.

Comment: Odd, Call PrintLog(log, "String here.") should work then.  I'm going to edit and make the parameters optional, as possibly somewhere in the calling code, it may not be including the object?

Answer (score 0):

```
' Write to a log file using Separator and Array of variant Parameters
' Auto generate the file
' USE EndLog to close    

'use: 
' PrintLog vbtab, "one", 2, 3
' PrintLog vbtab, "Apple","Windows","Linux","Android","Commodore","Amiga","Spectrum"
' EndLog

' Generate a csv file:
' PrintLog ";", rst!ID, rst!Name

Private FileLog As Object
Private fso As Object
Const DEBUG_LOG_FILE = "C:\log.txt"

Public Sub PrintLog(ByVal Separator As String, ParamArray Arguments() As Variant)
    Dim ele As Variant
    Dim line As String
    
    If FileLog Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set FileLog = fso.CreateTextFile(DEBUG_LOG_FILE, True, True)
    End If
    
    line = CStr(Now()) ' Print Timestamp

    For Each ele In Arguments
        If line > "" Then line = line & Separator
        line = line & CStr(ele)
    Next
    If line > "" Then FileLog.WriteLine line
End Sub

Public Sub EndLog()
    On Error Resume Next
    FileLog.Close
    Set FileLog = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```