# VBA code inside Excel doesn't run when triggered via Scheduler

Tags: windows, vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

So the setup on this WinServer 2012 R2 64bit is:

Windows Task Scheduler -> cscript .vbs file -> opening excel and run a sub in the main module

This runs fine in the background when I double click the .vbs file, but when I trigger the .vbs via the task scheduler, excel opens, but doesn't load the file or run the sub (not sure which). The task runs under an domain user that has administration rights on the machine. I use the same user when i try clicking on the .vbs

Code that is being run, in order:

***Task scheduler launches:***

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe "D:\xyz\trigger.vbs"

***.vbs does:***

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlsheets, xlcopy
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Interactive = False
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
xlapp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\xyz\excelfile.xlsm")

On Error Resume Next
Call xlBook.Application.Run("Main.Extrnal_Trigger")

xlbook.Saved = True
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlcopy = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit(1)
```

***Excel code:***

```
Sub Extrnal_Trigger()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Call update_button
Call MainProgram
Call ReportSave

End Sub
```

How can I find out where the .vbs or the excel hangs and why? A very similar setup on another machine does run without troubles. It is virtually identical to the code quoted here.

I realize there are several bad practices (like not cleaning up xlapp settings), but I'd like to get the process running before cleaning up.

---

/edit:
Removing

```
On Error Resume Next
```

from the .vbs does not display an error.

---

/edit2:
I tried reverting as far back as possible.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, f, s, log

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set log = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\xyz\TESTlog.txt")
log.WriteLine "before fso"

Set f = fso.GetFile("D:\xyz\excel.xlsm")
s = f.Path & "  "
s = s & "Created: " & f.DateCreated & "  "
s = s & "Last Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed & "  "
s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified   

log.WriteLine "after fso"
log.writeline "fso content"
log.writeline s
```

This works when being triggered by the task scheduler via cscript.exe.
I will try to modify to log what's happening around the call to the excel file.

---

/edit3:
Debugging showed that this

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\xyz\excel.xlsm")
```

never happens. I put out error numbers and got error 1004 for this call. Still not sure what's the issue, but at least I got an error number now.

---

/edit4:

error 1004 when trying to run this as a scheduled tasks persists. When I am running it by double clicking the .vbs, everything works.

Comment: Is *D:* assigned to a network drive by any chance? Have you tried logging information about the file (e.g. file size) to see, whether you can query information about the file? Have you tried opening the file using the file system object instead, to see, whether it is accessible in your specific setup?

Comment: Try a minimal example that only shows a MsgBox "Hello World". If that works, then add code.

Comment: im not sure under which user is scheduler works (probably under uncle of Bill Gates dunno), but i will check, if there isnt that anoying warning, that you have macros disabled, and you need to enable it. (not for yourself, but for scheduler)

Comment: D: is a local drive. Both the .vbs as well as the .xlms are on that drive. Like mentioned in my post. Double clicking on the .vbs works as intended.

I will still try to see if I can actually access the file. Give me a few minutes to see what's going on ...

Done. When I try with fso, I can access the file when double clicking the  .vbs normally. When I trigger the .vbs via the task scheduler (wither with wscript or cscript), the msgbox doesn't pop up. Not sure what's the problem here :(

Comment: @LubošSuk The task triggered by the scheduler runs under the same user I use to work on the machine. It's a domain user with admin rights on the machine.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Tried that ... the Msgbox doesn't show, but the task manager shows a cscrip or wscript process as background process. Is there some global setting that shifts all script and wscript executions to the background when they are called from a scheduled task?

Comment: @steW then i would try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645091/vba-sub-to-write-to-a-log-file  to log your errors into file. Then you can see if sheet throwing some error.

Comment: @LubošSuk will try that now. Thanks so far.

Comment: @steW and also throw this Application.DisplayAlerts = False on even begining of your code to prevent some magical popupbox

Comment: @brettdj Not sure what you mean. The .vbs doesn't throw an error. The VBA code in the excel also runs normally when triggered from within the excel or when I just doubleclick the .vbs instead of running it via a scheduled task.

Comment: I googled for "windows task scheduler foreground" and found an answer "_to cause the program to be interactive one must select "Run only when the user is logged on"_ in task scheduler

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yeah I found that later. I have since edited my original question with what I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was to create **both these folders**:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

and

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Excel apparently has troubles running in non-interactive mode when these folders are not present (not sure why). Creating them got rid ofthe 1004 error when opening the workbook via vbs.