# PI DataLink Add-In Not Loaded by Scheduled Task

Tags: excel, vba, osisoft

I have an Excel workbook with some VBA code, which uses the PISampDat function of the OSIsoft DataLink add-in to pull multiple columns of data.  The workbook is run by a batch file, which is in turn triggered by a Windows scheduled task.  If I run the workbook or the batch file manually, it works as expected, but if I use the scheduled task, I get the following error:

> 1004: Cannot run the macro 'PISampDat'. The macro may not be available
>   in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

"PISampDat" is not a macro but the name of a function in the add-in.  The code is as follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range(Cells(5, PTTagNamesCol), Cells(RangeRowCount, PTTagNamesCol)) = Application.Run("PISampDat", TagName, EDate, SDate, "5m", 0, PiServer)
```

It seems like when it's run by the scheduled task, Excel is not loading the DataLink add-in and therefore doesn't recognise the function name.

Further details:

- Scheduled task running as admin user which permissions on all files
  and folders involved
- "Run whether user is logged in or not" option
  selected
- "Run with highest privileges" option selected
- Configured for Windows Server 2012 R2
- "Program/script" option contains only the batch file name
- "Start in (optional)" option contains only the batch file path

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571522/vba-code-inside-excel-doesnt-run-when-triggered-via-scheduler

Comment: Have you tried configuring your task to run with the same user as well as loading the user profile?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration of your scheduled task it may run as a system user for which the user profile does not have access to the correct excel add-ins. It may also be that the task is running as a background task where threads have no access to the UI stuff...   There are many things and it could be complex.

I think that you may need to step back and ask yourself what you are trying to achieve? 
There are many many ways to consume data out of the PI System and it really depends of what you are trying to do. You could use .NET code with the AF SDK which is easier to automate than excel. As well you could use an ODBC client with the PI ODBC driver to query data out of the PI System and that is also easier to automate.  There is also the powershell scripts for the PI System that you could use... so many things.  Have a Look at the [PI Developer Technologies](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Products/Developer-Technologies/?_ga=2.63105839.1463434667.1567847010-1640013524.1539175473) and you may find another easier way to extract your data.

Once you get data in a flat file (e.g. csv), then you can easily consume it in excel with 
  a data refresh, same with powerbi.